# The SVM classifier.predict() function is giving wrong output

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to predict using SVM

```
#Create a svm Classifier
model = svm.SVC(C = 1,kernel='linear')# Linear Kernel
#Train the model using the training sets
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred
```

y_pred should contain 0 as well as 1 but y_pred only contains array of 0s[text]

Output:

```
y_pred =[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Where is the problem?

I was expecting y_pred to be an array of 0 and 1
but the output I am getting is not correct

Here's the dataset I am using:
[covid_data](https://github.com/akanksha0616/Covid_dataset.git)

Comment: The possible reasons could be - 1. Imbalanced dataset , check if the dataset contains ample amount of data with both classes, is not biased towards only 1 class. 2. Your model might not have learned enough try playing around with model parameters.